# How do I make an accountant come out as an object in my json?

Tags: java, json, spring, hibernate, jpql

This is my controller that called it from a class called demand that I want to get the states counter for its id

```
@SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "unchecked" })
    @CrossOrigin("http://localhost:8080")
    @RequestMapping(value = "countestado", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public List<Demanda> listadoxcount() {
    //  String hql = " SELECT  d.Estado_Demanda.nombre ,  con   cat(COUNT(d.Estado_Demanda.id) as total ,'-' ,d.Estado_Demanda.nombre )  FROM Demanda d  group by d.Estado_Demanda.id  ";
        String hql = " SELECT  d.Estado_Demanda.nombre , COUNT(d.Estado_Demanda.id) as total \r\n" + 
                "FROM Demanda d \r\n" +  
                "GROUP BY d.Estado_Demanda.id \r\n" + 
                "HAVING COUNT(d.Estado_Demanda.id) > 4";

        return EntityManager.createQuery(hql).getResultList()   ;
                }
```

Here is where I have my class bean, entity or model as you know

```
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id_demanda")
    private int id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_personas", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Persona personas;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_estado_demanda", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Estado_Demanda Estado_Demanda;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column
    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss")
    private Date fecha_registro;

    @Column
    private String comentario;

    @Column
    private String descripcion;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column
    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss")
    private Date fecha_entregada_solicitada;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column
    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss")
    private Date fecha_entrega_comprometida;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_tipo_prioridad", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Tipo_prioridade tipo_prioridade;

    @Column
    private int urgente;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_tipo_trama", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Tipo_trama tipo_trama;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_tipo_capa_red", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Tipo_capa_red tipo_capa_red;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_frame_rate", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private FrameRate frameRate;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_elemento_red_origen", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Elemento_red elemento_origen;

    @Column
    private String interfaz_ip_origen;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_elemento_red_destino", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Elemento_red elemento_destino;

    @Column
    private String interfaz_ip_destino;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_demanda", referencedColumnName = "id_demanda")
    private List<FlujoDemanda> flujoDemandas;

//Getters and Setters de Demanda

//Estado_demanda entidad
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private int id;

@Column
private String nombre;

@Column
private int activo;
```

and this is where I have the result of my json where I don't understand how I can do my accountant  that is look like a object please help meeeeeeeeee

```
 [
  [
    "cancelada",
    254
  ],
  [
    "en proceso",
    109
  ],
  [
    "entregada",
    574
  ],
  [
    "registrada",
    476
  ],
  [
    "cerrrado",
    5
  ]
]
```

Comment: The JSON that you show up is what you want?? Or it is what you're getting from the query `listadoxcount` ?? Do you want to return `Demanda` Objects as JSONs ??

Comment: I wanna get a object of count and I'M GETTING A QUERY OF LISTADOXCOUNT . IN OTHER WORDS  I WANT SOMETHING LOOK THIS : STATUS : REGISTRADA, STATUS TOTAL: (TOTAL OF NUMBER BY STATUS)